# Flowtype: function collections (throw errors) vs if conditions (does not throw)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, flowtype

I'm having some trouble trying to make unsound some code, and I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or it's a bug.

This code throws errors:
https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAQgNgewMYGs4gMIENgQOYIBOIUAvFAN4A+AUFFAEaKoDOAXFAIKGFYgA88ZGhAwsLCAFE4EALYQAdsAB8AGjpQAJhABmASwUQOAciQ58REMfX0FWeRxbBCBvDahIEiAK6EA-BwK3rIMEITuEAAeYFgK2poBjAheELHqVAC+ANw0ngpOHuYExADiimE4RGRQABQQMvJKHEKo6Ni4xSCqUHqakYHBoYQAlGTKtRr8Zh2WUCgQIKQUvZEZUHbyS-VyisAAdBsQa54+hFsNu3snCL5rUTFxEJrnO0p797HxawD0yjTDORooEgsGYIhaKGq1A02n0hhMTGE1g0wKMUCcLgUbhhehYWCYT0SDGSMjSNEyOTyBURqDKhl4wCq5DqFyaoOE6Ah3RWAxCYVGpHGNUmNMh80Wyz6a1RL0a+1Ra00uPxMmeFG2cr2SrxBM0Pz+AKB4GgEPQAGUIGAobR6LCDGjjBIwMj6HgsGBEkE+eFydlcgh8sB0Za6RVGYRqizXsBmmDzZbuX1eUMBULJk65gslis1m6wLLLnn9f9Aaj2a1ROIpKyg+RTaIwVAqOWRBawDky-WACok4mRaTR6r19oWYhNlucqsDuWAqlB0XoUMMogsKEaUUcUVLyo++jTUcgDg6MZQHTuJ2OEPlZc+v00ADaFBhuntCLBLqgqJMAFkEAA3CAADEiAAdywQhNGRDJuifW0X3hKBjFFD8v0Q38ALEVAwIgqCYOfOEHWQ9xUOMdCIAAJT0PAAAtgFwyh8NfRCiJRY0f3-CAABldDo9QMgAXT2WR3RqKM5VjDkQB7Lw+2nXZE0iVMGL3AMCjwa8d2qBcQG3cMWHvDVLjtQx+MBeg9GPGpUQQY91PpTSAEJSHIYwdG8BQkGAPQA2MUZYPoT9qMIBAQPWCBQskHgiBqAADLtqOgQylC0eC9C8gNEIAEnVGstXgo5jC0BAIFXBQECDKJcWAGLDXoDIaA0QgIGAXwFCgOyw2ipLgAUw0MgBIA

While this not: https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAQgNgewMYGs4gMIENgQOYIBOIUAvFAN4A+AUFFAEaKoDOAXFAIKGFYgA88ZGhAwsLCAFE4EALYQAdsAB8AGjpQAJhABmASwUQOAciQ58REMfX0FWeRxbBCBvDahIEiAK6EA-BwK3rIMEITuEAAeYFgK2poBjAheELHqVAC+ANw0ngpOHuYExADiimE4RGRQABQQMvJKHEKo6Ni4xSCqUHqakYHBoYQAlGTKtRr8Zh2WUCgQIKQUvZEZUHbyS-VyisAAdBsQa54+hFsNu3snCL5rUTFxEJrnO0p797HxawD0yjTDORooEgsGYIhaKGq1A02n0hhMTGE1g0wKMUCcLgUbhhehYWCYT0SDGSMjSNEyOTyBURqDKhl4wCq5DqFyaoOE6Ah3RWAxCYVGpHGNUmNMh80Wyz6a1RL0a+1Ra00uPxMmeFG2cr2SrxBM0Pz+AKB4GgEPQAGUIGAobR6LCDGjjBIwMj6HgsGBEkE+eFydlcgh8sB0Za6RVGYRqizXsBmmDzZbuX1eUMBULJk65gslis1m6wLLLnn9f9Aaj2a1ROIpKyg+RTaIwVAqOWRBawDky-WACok4mRaTR6r19oWYhNlucqsDuWAmg0ADaFA0tt09oRYJd9CgqJMAFkEAA3CAAMSIAHcsIRNJuMt0l1utKv4VBjKLN-Qdy-90exKgL1ebzvZdHzhB033cD9jT3Q8IAAJT0PAAAtgEAyhgLtZ9Xw3CDtygr8YIAGV0FD3AyABdPZZHdGoozlWMORAHsvD7addkTSJUzQ+g9B0WoNUuDDoFIYSXzfUZ7y3QgIGAXwFEYMFQwZIhaLYno+kNegMg0Hi+JrLUnyEkTHUtYxxOAp1FMqQgVKUdiNKgLTuN4mz9kEsgjOmUcrDMh9PM6Szwxcuyck0jQUUQwgEDPdYIGiyQeGUgADLtEOgfilBAgw9GAPQAxfAASdU9MEjJjC0BAIBYdYECDKJcWARLDQyAEgA

By the way, the final array is the same.

Thank you.

Comment: Heya, welcome to SO. It's super hard to compare these two examples. I can see there are differences in the code, but it would likely help to provide more concise snippets. Also generally good etiquette to include enough of an example in the question that people don't have to jump to another page. Thanks!

Comment: I will do it! Thank you for your feedback.